# query updating a timestamp column not mentioned in list of updates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, default

I want to update only one column in my database, but for some reason my mysql query updates another column as well.

my code looks a little like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE rackusage set totalDuration =".$timeDiff." where (rackID = '".$rackID."' and startTime LIKE '%".$getStartTime."%');";
            echo "<br>";
            echo $sql;
            echo "<br>";
            $res = mysql_query($sql);
```

It's in php. 
I only want to update the total Duration column, but for some reason the startTime column gets updated as well.
The output string looks like this:

```
UPDATE rackusage set totalDuration =30 where (rackID = '2' and startTime 
LIKE '%2017-05-30 18:34:36%');
```

This is the resultant database:

[image: DB]

Comment: please use prepared statements and do not use `mysql` functions. use either MYSQLi or PDO

Comment: Why do you have a bracket for the where clause?

Comment: Your image does not support your problem. But other than the wildcards on the startTime (unnecessary), the query looks correct.

Comment: might you have set default value of `startTime` which update that column on each execution.

Comment: I guess you mean *multiple rows* instead of *multiple columns*. All rows in your picture match your `WHERE` clause: They all have `rackID = 2` and they all have the same time.

Comment: Please show us the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE rackusage;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems likely your `startTime` column is defined with something like this.

```
startTime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

Change your `UPDATE` query to include `SET startTime = startTime` and you'll defeat the `ON UPDATE` part of the default. Something like this should do the trick.

```
UPDATE rackusage set  startTime = startTime, totalDuration =".$timeDiff."  ...
```

Comment: Your right! Thanks a lot! This was the issue! Damn. Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 0):

If O.Jones is right and you do not want to update the value for column statTime you can process this statement on your database:

```
ALTER TABLE rackusage 
CHANGE `startTime` `startTime` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: Cool :) Thanks :)